# Python doc string for overloaded methods

Tags: python, docstring

When defining a subclass with one or more method implementations overloaded from the base class, what's the standard convention/best practice for specifying a doc string for these methods?
No doc string, such that it is inherited from the base class? -> This is most in line with DRY principle. But when reading the code there is no explicit info available that the function is an overloaded one instead of a new method not present in the base class.
Or repeat a one-line method summary and refer for details to the base implementation?

Comment: Overridden, not overloaded. An overriden method does not inherit the doc string of the function it overrides, so the question is simply whether or not you provide a docstring for your function. Unless you explicitly call the method in the parent class, there isn't necessarily any relationship between the original method does and what the overriden one does.